# Taking complete backup of System and then restoring?

Tags: backup, restore

I am using kubuntu 10.04 and now I want to install Mac on my PC.

I have my data scattered in over 200 Gb and I want take a backup such that with one command all my data is saved into a single file.

Then if my MAC installation fails then just format my hard drive and restore the system in its original form.

I know about "dd" but I am skeptic about it .

Is it possible?

Comment: Don't be skeptic about `dd`, it is rock solid and proven ;)

Comment: `dd` is NOT a backup utility; it's a low level debugging swiss army knife.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Orion's answer, I would also throw [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) in to the mix. A FOSS alternative to Ghost and Acronis.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is 3rd party image backup and restoration software, like Acronis TrueImage or Norton Ghost.  Both can take both partition and whole image backups, which I think is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`dd` certainly works.

You can also use `tar` (this will compress the tar file, but will take a bit of time but will save space):

```
tar cvjpf <filename>.tar.bz2 <list of files and directories>
```